# ASP.NET Dynamic Data Running as Read-Only?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic-data

I've created a new ASP.NET Dynamic Data website and have used LINQ-to-SQL for the framework. I start up the application and it displays my tables fine and I can browse them - but it doesn't give me any create/update/delete abilities - all I can do is read? I didn't change anything from the defaults - what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you don't have the primary keys set in your database.

Comment: Found this out the hard way. In Entity Domain Model, you also get some nice javascript ajax errors...